# Thread declaration

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, declaration

I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Try extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton n1 = new JButton("1");
JButton n2 = new JButton("2");
JButton n3 = new JButton("3");
JButton show = new JButton("Show");

{
show.addActionListener(this);
n1.setEnabled(false);
n2.setEnabled(false);
n3.setEnabled(false);

}

public Try(){
  super("Try");
  setVisible(true);
  setSize(500, 200);
  setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
  add(n1);
  add(n2);
  add(n3);
  add(show);
}  

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
Object clicked = a.getSource();
if(show == clicked){
new Trial().start();
}
}

class Trial extends Thread{
  public void run(){
        try {
            n1.setEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            n1.setEnabled(false);
            n2.setEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            n2.setEnabled(false);
            n3.setEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            n3.setEnabled(false);    
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
}
}      

    public static void main(String[] args){
      Try frame = new Try();
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    }
```

I have some questions regarding this certain parts:

```
1.--->     new Trial().start();
2.--->     class Trial extends Thread
3.--->     public void run()
```

1. why did he new it instead of just Trial? Or is line 1 a code to "make" a thread? is start a method in thread to create them?
2. Why did it extend thread? why can't it be simply class Trial? And also why isn't it set to public?
3. Why is it public? I understand tho that run runs the thread but why public?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whose code is this? If you're trying to learn from it, don't. It's not well written as it is making changes to Swing component states from a background thread, and this can cause unpredictable crashes.

Comment: Have a glance at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) first, then go to the src.

Comment: I've made the gui code but I copied the thread code and I wanna learn it.

Comment: That's not a good example of threading since most all Swing calls need to be queued on the Swing event thread (also known as the Event Dispatch Thread or EDT).

Comment: The questions you're asking seem to be about some fairly fundamental Java concepts. Maybe you should start with a general tutorial on the language before trying to throw an app together: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read some nice tutorial on java threads easily available online and you can find your answers after a little research which you must do before posting your question here.

Short answers to your questions are;

```
new Trial().start();
```

The new keyword is a java operator which creates the class object and start() is to start the execution of the thread.  it could be written like this as well;

```
Trial t = new Trial();
t.start();
```

So it means, whenever you create an object of a class which extends Thread, a new thread is created which will start executing when you call start()

```
class Trial extends Thread
```

Class Trial is extending a Thread class to inherit the behavior, and is able to override the run() function for its own implementation. In simple words, run() is the function where Thread does all of its working.

```
public void run()
```

run() function is overridden in derived class (i.e. Trial in your case) so it has to be public so that you can create and start a thread anywhere just creating the object of Trial class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: (3rd sentence, below the Trial t = new Trial(); t.start();)So its like in my gui code the extend JFrame, so I don't have to do it like JFrame Try = new JFrame("Try") ?

Comment: When your class extends a class, it extends the behavior of the parent class, so when you'll create the object of your class like Try t = new Try(); so "t" object will have access to Try class as well as the parent class's public functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Again, your Swing threading is in error, but regardless, I wouldn't even use threads directly but rather would use a Swing Timer for this. For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Try extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
   JButton n1 = new JButton("1");
   JButton n2 = new JButton("2");
   JButton n3 = new JButton("3");
   private JButton[] buttons = {n1, n2, n3};
   JButton show = new JButton("Show");
   private Timer timer = null;

   public Try() {
      super("Try");
      // setSize(500, 200);
      setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
      add(n1);
      add(n2);
      add(n3);
      add(show);

      show.addActionListener(this);
      n1.setEnabled(false);
      n2.setEnabled(false);
      n3.setEnabled(false);

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
      Object clicked = a.getSource();
      if (show == clicked && timer == null) {
         timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
         timer.setInitialDelay(0);
         timer.start();
      }
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      private int count = 0;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         for (JButton btn : buttons) {
            btn.setEnabled(false);
         }

         if (count != buttons.length) {
            buttons[count].setEnabled(true);
            count++;
         } else {
            timer.stop();
            timer = null;
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      new Try().setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```